# How does resourcemanager decide how many vcores a PC has?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager, cpu-cores

I have recently installed Hadoop on my PC, and am trying to run it on Ubuntu 16.10 32 Bit OS.

After I installed it, I installed pig and tried to run store into commands, when it froze. I searched for a few examples, when I noticed `resourcemanager` and `nodemanager` are not running.

I tried to find the root cause by calling `nodemanager` and `resourcemanager` manually, and then realised the error message. It said my PC did not have the minimum number of required v-cores, and `resourcemanager` signalled it to stop.

I browsed a few more articles, and saw that we need to lower the minimum values by defining them in `site.xml`. First I tried to set number of vcores by setting yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores to 1. I then tried to start `nodemanager`,  but it still didn't start up. It gave the same error message, about the minimum number of required resources not being available.

However, the `resourcemanager` did start up. I tried to set it to zero. At this time `resourcemanager` stopped, stating that the number of resources should be greater than 0. However, the `nodemanager` deamon started, and tried to connect to `resourcemanager`.

I tried it couple of times more, but am not sure why it says minimum resource is not available.

I have set a pretty low minimum memory allocation (100 MB), and have set the maximum memory limit to 500 MB. I have also set the min and max vcores to 1. I still can't figure out a way to start yarn. I am new to Hadoop.

I have 4 GB RAM, and an Intel i3 CPU. By running task manager I can see 4 cores.